# How to upload a file to S3 bucket using "BatchPutDocument" service?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kendra

we are running a javascript application with a search bar. The content is searchable from S3 bucket of AWS.
JavaScript application code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="aws-sdk-2.604.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var kendra = new AWS.Kendra({
            apiVersion: '2019-02-03',
           // region: '*****',
            accessKeyId: '*********',
            secretAccessKey: '*******************'
        });

        function getResults() {

            var searchText = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
            var params = {
                IndexId: '**************************',
                /* required */
                QueryText: searchText,
                PageNumber: '1',
                PageSize: '20'
            };
            kendra.query(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerText = data.ResultItems[0].DocumentTitle.Text;

                    console.log(data); // successful response
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is Kendra application</h1>

    <input type="text" id="searchBox" />
    <button onclick="getResults()">Search</button>
    <div>
        <b>search results</b>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The above javascript application includes a search bar which gives data from S3 bucket. Now we need to upload a new file using the "BatchPutDocument" Service code give below. The uploaded document(html or pdf) should be searchable in the javascript application search box.

Note : we should not directly upload file in s3 bucket by going to AWS s3 bucket.
Is the code give below helpful or any alternative code available.

```
var params = {
  Documents: [ /* required */
    {
      Id: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      AccessControlList: [
        {
          Access: ALLOW | DENY, /* required */
          Name: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
          Type: USER | GROUP /* required */
        },
        /* more items */
      ],
      Attributes: [
        {
          Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
          Value: { /* required */
            DateValue: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
            LongValue: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
            StringListValue: [
              'STRING_VALUE',
              /* more items */
            ],
            StringValue: 'STRING_VALUE'
          }
        },
        /* more items */
      ],
      Blob: Buffer.from('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' /* Strings will be Base-64 encoded on your behalf */,
      ContentType: PDF | HTML | MS_WORD | PLAIN_TEXT | PPT,
      S3Path: {
        Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
        Key: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
      },
      Title: 'STRING_VALUE'
    },
    /* more items */
  ],
  IndexId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  RoleArn: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
kendra.batchPutDocument(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Kendra allows you to index the documents in your Kendra index using available [Connectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/data-source.html) it offers or using [BatchPutDocument API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/in-adding-documents.html). When using [BatchPutDocument API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/in-adding-documents.html) you can either pass the document [inline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/in-adding-binary-doc.html) to Kendra or [pass an S3 URL of your document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/in-adding-plain-text.html) that you want to index. Once you have indexed your documents successfully, you will be able to perform a [search](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/searching-example.html) using Kendra's [Query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/API_Query.html). I see that you already have some Javascript code to invoke Kendra's Query API, however, you could also refer to [Kendra's provided sample React application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/deploying.html) if you are interested in building a React app.